# Python: cannot print (execution flow ?)

Tags: python

I am interested in a small python application, which can be downloaded here:
https://launchpad.net/treemap

If you run it, like this:

```
python treemap-basic.py examle-world-population.txt
```

It works just fine.
The problem is that even if I type a print command in the "treemap-basic.py" file:

```
print "Hello World !" @ treemap-basic.py
```

I cannot see the message "Hello World !" at the Terminal. Why?

Comment: Maybe because the "Hello World !" is being written to the example-world-population.txt file you provide in the arguments?

Comment: The syntax `print "Hello World!" @ treemap-basic.py` is invalid, so you should get a syntax error if that's what you're doing.  If without the `@`etc it should work fine when properly aligned in various possible parts of the code -- _where_ are you placing it? Are you aligning it correctly?  Is the `examle` spelling deliberate or just one more careless typo?  Hard to help you more than this, based on such scant info.

Comment: i meant that if i write :
print "Hello World !"
in the file treemap-basic.py,
for example, in line 64

i do not see the message displayed

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this script, and inserted

```
print "Hello World"
```

on line 64. When simply trying ./treemap-basic.py on the terminal, you get an IndexError since treemap-basic.py expects a command line argument. When you specify a file to work on:

```
./treemap-basic examle-world-population.txt
```

You see a bunch of output in stout. If you scroll up to the top (right below where you first entered the command in the terminal) you should see "Hello World" as the first line of output.